# I keep getting this same error when i try to submit an appointment request to sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert

I'm pretty new to sql and php.

I'm trying to submit this form into mysql server but I keep getting this error...i'm not sure where the mistake is...

> Error: INSERT INTO grooming (Address, Breed, City, Email, Firstname,
> Lastname, NeuteredOrSpayed, PetName, PetType, PhoneNumber, State, Zip)
> VALUES ('123 Main St','Chihuahua','Los
> Angeles','blankemail@gmail.com','John','Doe','Yes','Iris','Dog','(555)123-4568','CA','90001')
> Incorrect integer value: 'Yes' for column 'NeuteredOrSpayed' at row 1

This is the code:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pwdpwd";
$dbname = "pet_shop";


$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error();
} else {

function clean_data($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}


$firstname = clean_data($_POST['aptfirstname']);
$lastname = clean_data($_POST['aptlastname']);
$address = clean_data($_POST['aptaddress']);
$city = clean_data($_POST['aptcity']);
$state = clean_data($_POST['aptstate']);
$zip = clean_data($_POST['aptzip']);
$phonenumber = clean_data($_POST['aptphonenumber']);
$email = clean_data($_POST['aptemail']);
$petname = clean_data($_POST['aptpetname']);
$neutered = clean_data($_POST['aptneutered']);
$pettype = clean_data($_POST['aptpettype']);
$breed = clean_data($_POST['aptbreed']);



if ($neutered == "true") {
    $neutered = "Yes";
} else {
    $neutered = "No";
}

if ($pettype == "Cat") {
    $breed = ""; 
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO grooming (Address, Breed, City, Email, FirstName, LastName, NeuteredOrSpayed, PetName, PetType, PhoneNumber, State, Zip) VALUES ('$address', '$breed', '$city', '$email', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$neutered', '$petname', '$pettype', '$phonenumber', '$state', '$zip')";

if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "success"; 
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $db->error;
}

$db->close();
}


?>
```

If you need more context to the form code I can post that as well, it was just a lot to post up on here

Comment: you are inserting `Yes` in a integer field, i don't understand which part of the error you can't understand ...

Comment: What is the schema for your grooming table?  Based on the error message, you need to use an integer value instead of the string value of True/False.

Comment: Also, you are heavily opened to SQL injection

Comment: Note: your `clean_data()` does not clean data at all

Comment: Stop. See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Its a simple datatype error the column you have in database called neutered has a datatype of `Integer` and the value you trying to insert is 'Yes' which is absolutely not an `integer`.

Try putting integer 1 and 0 for yes and no respectively.

Answer (score 0):

it's very clear.. as @Berto99 and @Pete and others mentioned..

column 'NeuturedOrSpayed' datatype is INT, so in your code it should be like this

```
if ($neutered == "true") {
    $neutered = 1; # it was 'Yes' --> string, need to be int, so 1
} else {
    $neutered = 0; # it was 'No' --> string, need to be int, so 0
}
```

Comment: I'm an idiot for not catching that, thank you everyone

Comment: missing something is normal, cause you are new to php and sql. not trying to look the error message is not normal. *hope youre not the 2nd one ;)